# Mac freezing, possible virus?

Tags: macos, mac

I am running Yosemite and experiencing very nasty freezing issues. Once I was able to recover from by reinstalling osx and second time (few months later) reinstalling alone didn't help, but also downgrading user from Admin rights did.

Here are the symptoms:

- freezing applications, wheel mouse icon, occurring every 30 seconds or so and lasting about the same time.
- CPU usage is near zero. Idle ~97%
- ran opensnoop, but it didn't correlate to frezing
- once freeze occurs, 'top' any Activity Monotor do not show any activity - they freeze too. But, after freeze ends, I can see the spike in CPU activity. Activity Monitor replays the past events in a fast-forward kind of way, at 10x speed. But there is no way to tell what activity transpired. System was frozen.
- it feels like 1/4 of one core of cpu is actually being used for OS itself.
- no hardware issues were discovered with AHT.
- Safe mode had no impact.

In the screenshot bellow, there is a blimp in CPU usage. That's the freeze. Sometimes they happen for longer, sometimes shorter duration.

[image]

I know it's relatively vague problem description, but I would like to hear some theories on what this could be. And if it happens again, how to actually pin point to the process that is causing it.

Comment: does it occur with and without network / Internet connection?

Comment: yes. I turned off wifi once to test that - it had no effect on the freezing.

Answer (score 1):

You can check which processes are using the most time interval in the system calls:

```
sudo fs_usage | grep -v 0.0000
```

<sup>See: [How do I debug an out-of-control “kernel_task” process?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/232402/22781)</sup>

In case your macOS experienced out-of-space scenario, some services can be still in a freeze mode (causing some freeze timeouts) and they need manual unpause by the following command:

```
kill -CONT -1
```

Otherwise check whether clean restart helps with anything.

If you had any unexpected shutdown after freeze, it's good to check for the [shutdown code](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/126588/22781).

If won't help, if you experience another freeze, hit <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>⌥</kbd>-<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>,</kbd> (*Cmd-Opt-Ctrl-Shift-Period*), this will trigger `sysdiagnose` process which will quickly gather system-wide diagnostic information helpful in investigating system memory/performance issues (will appear in `/var/tmp`). If you're technical person, you can consider uncompressing the generated file and analyse the logs, or contact Apple support if they can help you.

If you believe you've a virus, just install antivirus (such as [Sophos Home](https://home.sophos.com/)) to exclude that. But having antivirus, can cause [another extra freezes](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/145633/22781) as well, so it's up to you.